# Are these four "special weapon properties" roughly similar in power?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review

Assume you have multiple weapons such as the glaive, halberd, and pike that are (in stock 5e) identical other than name (and possibly damage type, but that rarely matters and can be ignored for this question).

Give each of them a different one of these four properties.

- **Accurate**: Add a +1 modifier to the attack roll for weapon attacks made with this weapon.
- **Arcing**: When you hit with a weapon attack using this weapon, a second creature within your reach that the attack roll would hit takes damage of the weapon's type equal to your proficiency bonus as well.
- **Reliable**: When you miss with a weapon attack using this weapon, the target takes damage equal to half your proficiency bonus regardless.
- **Wounding**: When you hit with a weapon attack using this weapon and the amount rolled on any die is less than half your proficiency bonus rounded up, treat it as if it was half your proficiency bonus rounded up[1].

**Question**: Are each of these new weapons *still* roughly similar such that there are reasons to use any one of them and none of them are strictly dominated/dominant. Situationally weaker or stronger is fine, but globally "never pick that one" or "always pick this other one" is not.

[1] These would be "turned on" at level 5 by a class feature, so half-round-up of proficiency is always 2+.

Comment: For "Wounding", when you say "any die" do you mean any die from the weapon itself? Or any damage die associated with the attack at all? Say, Sneak Attack or Divine Smite damage dice?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Whichever would bring it closer into balance with the others. I don't have a strong preference. A great answer would consider both interpretations.

Comment: If all of these features are only available after level 5 and require a class feature (i.e. only available to certain classes) I think that should be mentioned somewhere more prominent than a footnote that seems intended to only relate to one of them. There should also be more information about what classes would have access to this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### They're very different in impact

For my analysis I take two Fighters.

One is level 5, STR+4, Proficiency+3, and two Attacks with a Pike. The opponent has AC 14.

One is level 13, STR+5, Proficiency+5, and three Attacks with a Pike. The opponent has AC 18.

#### Analysis

*Accurate* increases chance to hit by 5%. That's an increase in average damage of 0.85 per turn and 1.425 with the examples above. This effect is better the more benefits you get from an attack. I.e. if the bonus damage (like Smites) can make the damage increase much better than your other effects. Other on-hit bonuses can also be more relevant than the damage bonus and increase the value of this effect.

*Arcing* can do a lot more damage **if** a suitable target is nearby. 4.2 damage per turn and 9.75 on average. But the effect does nothing against a single opponent or if multiple opponents are spaced out too much.

*Reliable* does an extra 0.6 or 2.1 damage on average (miss chance * half Prof * number of attacks). The damage increase compares more favorably to the other effects the less likely you are to hit.

Both *Arcing* and *Reliable* are especially valuable when dealing low amounts of damage is sufficient to get a benefit, e.g. to get the higher damage from *Toll the Dead* or against opponents who are very low on hit points.

*Wounding* does an extra 0.07 or 0.39 damage in the examples on average. This is highly dependent on the number of dice used per attack. The more dice and the smaller, the better the effect. With the 1d10 attacks of the weapons you suggest, it does almost nothing. For example with 2d6 on Greatsword it is 0.23 and 1.3. If this would work on Sneak Attack dice or similar, this would be very good.

### Conclusion

None of these effects is strictly better than any other *per se*, except that *Wounding* is very bad with the specific weapons you suggest.

Comment: Matches my estimations as well. I'd say that arcing would offer about 10-20% DPS increase in adventures, due to requirement to position and fighting more than one enemy. Reliable - seems to be working with Haxblade's curse, which may allow to tripple damage.

Comment: Arcing is very dependent on the game. I run almost exclusively combats with 3 to 8 opponents so it would probably work most of the time. If you run mostly solo opponents it's very bad.

Comment: Good analysis. Is there any reason in particular for choosing those specific opponent AC values?

Comment: I had a quick look at the suggested AC for specific CRs in the DMG.

Comment: It might be helpful to add that Accurate increases in power whenever there are additional sources of damage beyond weapon damage that depend on a hit (e.g. sneak attack, smites, maneuvers...). Similarly, effects playing off of dealing damage / enemies being damaged increase the value of both arcing and reliable (toll the dead is the only thing that comes to mind right now but I am sure there are others).

Comment: @Surpriser Added mentions of this. This is not a spell or feature, but just dealing damage is useful against opponents low on HP.

Comment: @Sarge I'd rule it to not trigger any "on hit" effects like curse, hex, smite, sneak attack, etc.

Anagkai: Thanks for the analysis. Takeaway is that Wounding needs a rework. It's intended to apply to "sword like" martial weapons generally.